# Image processing in C — processing a 256-color bitmap image

Tags: c, turbo-c, bgi

I am using Borland Turbo C and the Borland Graphics Interface.

I have two questions:

1. I have to process a 256 color bitmap image. It is difficult to process using EGAVGA driver, so I decided to use SVGA driver. It works fine, but when I convert the image into gray scale, instead of showing only the image in gray scale, the whole window goes into gray scale mode. Is there any method to change the color palette for a specific area using `outp(0x03c8, data)` and `outp(0x03c9, data)` functions?
2. The mouse functions works fine with EGAVGA mode but the cursor is not visible in the SVGA mode. Even the mouse is functional. How could I create a custom mouse cursor for SVGA mode in 256 color? I have the codes for creating custom mouse pointer in EGAVGA mode using 0x10 interrupt but it is not working with SVGA mode?

Comment: Do you refer to a specific area of the palette table or a specific area in your picture?

Comment: Do you have any Code? I don't know if it matters, but, what operating system are you using?

Comment: @mcleod_ideafix Specific area.

Comment: @EvanCarslake Windows

Comment: Windows with interrupt 0x10 ???

Comment: Windows with "EGAVGA mode" ??? Perhaps OP is using the DOS command line, and programming "in DOS".

Comment: @Aswin : more information is needed. Which Windows version, which compiler, are you using a DOS session or are you writting a Windows GUI application?

Comment: Aswin is using Turbo C; that is an antique (probably older than he is).

Comment: Also, @mcleod_ideafix: removing relevant tags like [tag:turbo-c] and [tag:bgi] and then asking 'which compiler and graphics mode are you using' is really not fair!

Comment: I put those tags because I assumed he was using Turbo C and BGI. Then he said he was using Windows so I removed them. Now he has updated his question and stated that he is actually not using Windows, but Turbo C and BGI (or have you edited his question to show that?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In paletized video modes, palette entries affect the whole screen. If you change any index, all pixels on screen with that index will change, whether if they belong to your image or not.

If your image is going to share the screen with others, and you want that image the only one that changes into grayscale, you have to set aside some palette entries for exclusive use by your image, so changing them won't affect other graphic elements in your screen.

On Windows, and X-Window if my memory serves well, the entire screen will have the colours of your palette when your window application has the focus. When not, it will revert to system palette and your windows and its contents will show "weird".

Comment: Okay.Is it possible to change if its specific area of picture

Comment: Only if that specific area of your picture has pixels with indexes that are not used in any other part of your picture

Comment: This is why pictures are processed using 24-bit pixels, and only rendered to a paletized mode when you want to show them on screen

Comment: In the windows95 days when you get focus you could set your palette as the one being displayed. When you lose focus someone else can. What you're supposed to do is cope with whatever palette is displayed as best you can, to allow this you will get notified whenever it changes.